# Codeigniter: Error in loading HMVC sub module model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am having trouble loading model in sub module controller from sub module itself.

I am having few modules and sub-modules as below

```
modules/admin/
modules/admin/models
modules/admin/controllers
modules/admin/views

modules/admin/models/dashboard/
modules/admin/controllers/dashboard/
modules/admin/views/dashboard/

modules/admin/models/plugs/
modules/admin/controllers/plugs/
modules/admin/views/plugs/
```

Each M/V/C has own files in it.

Now I have created model in modules/admin/models/plugs/ just for testing purpose something like below

**Plugs Model**

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Plugs extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();    

    }


    public function mymeta()
    {
        return 'plugs model loded';
    }

}
```

And now trying to load into **Plugs Controller** as below

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Plugs extends MX_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('plugs');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('plugs/index');
    }

    public function get_plugin_meta()
    {
        echo $this->plugs->mymeta(); // this is the method from Plugs Models
    }   

}
```

But when I tried to access the URL `http://localhost/mysite/admin/plugs/get_plugin_meta` or `http://localhost/mysite/admin/plugs` it is giving me below error.

```
An Error Was Encountered

Unable to locate the model you have specified: plugs
```

**So than how to load model in controller?**

Comment: Did you try `$this->load->model('admin/plugs');` ?

Comment: Yes giving the same error.. :(

Comment: Can you tell me file path where exactly? `modules/admin/models/plugs/plugs.php` ?

Comment: That's right. It is on the same path.. `root/application/modules/admin/models/plugs/plugs.php` and my controller is in `root/application/modules/admin/controllers/plugs/plugs.php`

Comment: Anybody please help me to resolve this. I think this is a major issue if we can't load model from sub module. It should have some resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your module is not `plugs`. It's `admin` because of `modules/admin`

You should use like `$this->load->model('module/model');`

Try this one:

```
$this->load->model('admin/plugs/plugs'); // module/folder/file
```

### Important

Controller class name and model class name was conflicting.

Just rename model filename with: `plugs_model.php`

and change class name with: `class Plugs_model extends CI_Model`

```
$this->load->model('admin/plugs/plugs_model'); 
echo $this->plugs_model->mymeta(); // plugs model loded
```

Comment: I have tried this too but than browser keep searching the page and never loads.

Comment: This is just weird. Can't get it.. what's wrong can't udnerstand

Comment: I have cross checked by placing model in default `application/models/ `structure and it is loading without any problem. This means there is something wrong with HMVC

Comment: I'm using https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc this ext and my code works successfull `plugs model loded`

Comment: I am also using the same than why doesn't work for me? :( very staring.. can you please provide me your structures and file so I can cross check with mine. You can upload on bitbucket or github if possible.. I would appreciate.

Comment: Oh I think I have to set modules path in config file. Is it?

Comment: third_party/MX/Modules.php check paths like `APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',`

Comment: Yeah it is already there in the right place `is_array(Modules::$locations = $CFG->item('modules_locations')) OR Modules::$locations = array(
 APPPATH.'modules/' => '../modules/',
);`

Comment: If you set `modules_locations` before in for example config.php, this may cause malfunction.

Comment: I can't find the config settings you updated in answer. DO I need to add it manually?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44673/discussion-between-pixelngrain-and-bora)

Comment: can we please continue on chat?