# Codeigniter HMVC: Second child module not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please refer this question [Codeigniter: Error in loading HMVC sub module model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945935/codeigniter-error-in-loading-hmvc-sub-module-model)

Now I am setting up second level of module like

```
mysite.com/admin/hr/positions/
```

Directory structure is this

```
modules/admin/
modules/admin/models
modules/admin/controllers
modules/admin/views

modules/admin/models/dashboard/
modules/admin/controllers/dashboard/
modules/admin/views/dashboard/

modules/admin/models/hr/
modules/admin/controllers/hr/
modules/admin/views/hr/

modules/admin/models/hr/positions
modules/admin/controllers/hr/positions
modules/admin/views/hr/positions
```

Now I have respective MCV for every directory. Example Admin, Dashboard, HR and Positions. The system works fine till HR so if I enter `site.com/admin/hr/` it is giving output

but when I try to access positions page `site.com/admin/hr/positions/` it is giving me **404** no idea what is wrong in it?

Is it because that module is under **HR** ?

I am loading view `$this->load->view('admin/hr/positions/index', $this->data);` this way.

Comment: Where are your controllers and how are they named? Do you have hr.php? positions.php? What functions are in there?

Comment: I have hr.php file and positions.php as well. Every folder has own controller with the respecitive name. `admin` has `Admin extends MX_Controller`,`hr` has HR_exttends MX_Controller` and so forth..

Answer (score 0):

The controller name is part of the path as well.

To access `function index()` of `class Positions` in `/admin/hr/positions/` you need to call `/admin/hr/positions/positions/`.

To avoid that, move the Controller file `positions.php` to /hr/.

The path structure of CodeIgniter is always `/path/to/controller/controller_name/function_name/as/many/parameters/as/you/want`.